# Visual Studio 2010 indentation in a .aspx file breaks after starting a new code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, formatting

I have a block of C# code that I want to write some HTML within:

```
if ( someCondition ) {
    %><span>its_important_my_span_has_no_spaces_around_it</span><%
}

int x = 0;
// ...
```

But in Visual Studio 2010, after the <%, I hit Enter and I get

```
if ( someCondition ) {
    %><span>its_important_my_span_has_no_spaces_around_it</span><%
                                                                     }

                                                                     int x = 0;
                                                                     // ...
```

It even re-formats this way automatically (e.g., when I type the semicolon).

I keep poking around the **Options** > **Text Editor** area in HTML and C# to figure out what to turn on or off but I'm at a loss.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

If I highlight that first **}** and re-type it, it puts it in the right place.

Comment: Why is it important that your span not have spaces?  If there are formatting issues they may be solvable with CSS.

Comment: By looking at the code in the example, it looks like his problem is with the auto formatting of the C# code.

Comment: Also, in your example, your span doesn't have spaces around it in either of those two code blocks.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson I understand what he's _asking_, but I'm wondering if the _actual problem_ (the fact that the span can't have whitespace around it) can be solved another way.  The reason the formatting gets messed up is because he can't put the server tags on the lines before and after the span like you normally would.

Comment: But, he can do that. And he may have a CSS problem, but that's not his question.

Comment: When the spaces in HTML don't matter as much, I've been using <% if (...) { %> one one line and then <% } %> later. It's visually obnoxious but workable (and becomes nicer in Razor syntax later). It's just for short runs or space-critical portions that I use the format in question.

Comment: @DStanley Spaces mess up IE6 sometimes. Plus they count as a text node, which can be good or bad depending on the context.

Comment: Unless you are working within a specific environment that needs IE6, you really should stop caring about it. Less than .5% of the world is still using it: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: I'm working within a specific environment that uses IE6 - the other half of the world. If it looks crappy to them, it's going to reflect badly on me/us. I tried not to care but IE6 is like that old girlfriend you tried to break up with that keeps sending you birthday cards.

Answer (score 1):

This is always going to be a PITA. Simple way to deal with it though. Immediately after you hit Enter (or any action that auto formats) press Alt+Backspace and move on.

Alternatively, you can go to your Text Editor options and remove all auto formatting for C#, but i don't think you'll want to do that because that will apply to all of your code-behind files.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about Alt+Backspace. I bumped into that a while back but I haven't made it a habit yet.

Comment: Yeah. I don't have VS 2012 yet, but I hope they fix this. It's a minor headache once you get in the habit of immediately undoing it.